# Zookeeper will create a password for client by sessionId, and so we can forge it by sessionId, is't any security issue?

Tags: java, apache-zookeeper

Zookeeper implement logical as picture show, anyone know it, does is a securty issue?
[image]

i try to simulate zookeeper logical, use same method  we can easy get same password by session Id.

```
private static final long superSecret = 0XB3415C00L;
static byte[] generatePasswd(long id) {
    Random r = new Random(id ^ superSecret);
    byte[] p = new byte[16];
    r.nextBytes(p);
    return p;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    byte[] passwd = new byte[16];

    long sessionId = 11L;

    Random r = new Random(sessionId ^ superSecret);
    r.nextBytes(passwd);

    System.out.println(passwd);

    byte[] ps = generatePasswd(sessionId);

    System.out.println(generatePasswd(sessionId));

    boolean rs = Arrays.equals(passwd, generatePasswd(sessionId));
    System.out.println(rs);
}
```

Comment: Don't you need to know what `superSecret` is ahead of time? Otherwise, you should report this in Zookeeper JIRA, probably, but Zookeeper is typically protected by TLS certificates, not passwords.

Comment: superSecret  is hard code in Zookeeper project